# MongoDB join two collections having JSON array data

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am able to write query for normal single key-value joining with `$lookup`. But my scenario is little bit complicated, and not sure how to achieve that.

**product :**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("6200a77598412e443c03f0ee"),
    "name": "1000",
    "sku_code": "22",
    "field_values": [{
        "field_id": ObjectId("61fd34cbbc787e45d256a270"),
        "key": "P4YZRK71CZAQ8IXJ3",
        "value": "54"
    }, {
        "field_id": ObjectId("61fb77b2384e2635f8a2d1ea"),
        "key": "SF_10KRUMSESSIONSPERMONTH",
        "value": "34"
    }]
}
```

**field :**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("61fb77b1384e2635f8a2d1e9"),
    "description": "sf_infrastructureFunction__c",
    "is_read_only": false,
    "is_required": false,
    "name": "sf_infrastructureFunction",
    "key": "SF_INFRASTRUCTUREFUNCTION",
    "type": "number"
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("61fb77b2384e2635f8a2d1ea"),
    "default": "123",
    "description": "sf_10KRumSessionsPerMonth__c",
    "is_read_only": false,
    "is_required": false,
    "name": "sf_10KRumSessionsPerMonth",
    "key": "SF_10KRUMSESSIONSPERMONTH",
    "type": "number"
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("61fd34cbbc787e45d256a270"),
    "description": "UKXNVYBF7AXE1VOUH",
    "is_read_only": false,
    "is_required": true,
    "name": "P4YZRK71CZAQ8IXJ3",
    "key": "P4YZRK71CZAQ8IXJ3",
    "type": "number"
}
```

**Final expected output for product(6200a77598412e443c03f0ee) :**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("61fb77b1384e2635f8a2d1e9"),
    "description": "sf_infrastructureFunction__c",
    "is_read_only": false,
    "is_required": false,
    "name": "sf_infrastructureFunction",
    "key": "SF_INFRASTRUCTUREFUNCTION",
    "type": "number",
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("61fb77b2384e2635f8a2d1ea"),
    "default": "123",
    "description": "sf_10KRumSessionsPerMonth__c",
    "is_read_only": false,
    "is_required": false,
    "name": "sf_10KRumSessionsPerMonth",
    "key": "SF_10KRUMSESSIONSPERMONTH",
    "type": "number",
    "field_data" : {
        "key": "SF_10KRUMSESSIONSPERMONTH",
        "value": "34"
    }
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("61fd34cbbc787e45d256a270"),
    "description": "UKXNVYBF7AXE1VOUH",
    "is_read_only": false,
    "is_required": true,
    "name": "P4YZRK71CZAQ8IXJ3",
    "key": "P4YZRK71CZAQ8IXJ3",
    "type": "number",
    "field_data" : {
        "key": "P4YZRK71CZAQ8IXJ3",
        "value": "54"
    }
}
```

Kindly note in first JSON in sample output, product has not stored any `field_values` for that field. Overall, I want all fields data with their values for specific product id, and if it does not have values, then plain configuration of field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
db.field.aggregate([
{
 "$lookup": {
  "from": "product",
  "localField": "_id",
  "foreignField": "field_values.field_id",
  "as": "field_data"
 }
 },
 {
   $unwind: {
    path: "$field_data",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
 }
 },
 {
  "$addFields": {
  "field_data": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$field_data.field_values",
      "as": "fv",
      "cond": {
        $eq: [
          "$$fv.field_id",
          "$_id"
        ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
   },
   {
    $addFields: {
     field_data: {
      $cond: {
       if: {
        $eq: [
          "$field_data",
          null
        ]
       },
       then: "$$REMOVE",
       else: "$field_data"
      }
     }
    }
   }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. $lookup to add the product to the field documents
2. $unwind to flatten the resulting array ( it contain product document ) preserving the null elements
3. $filter to keep only the matching products.
4. Remove the null field_data for those products that is null.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OOH14tgklwi)

Comment: Thanks, this is really close to what I need. Only remaining tricky part is, it is missing the field where there is no data. So, expected result is 3 fields.

Comment: Ah just saw the missed points and correct , please, check now is exactly as expected